# Merge javascript array in array with same key using loop

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, reactjs

What is the best way to reorganize an array into output? I need to merge all value keys (whether array or not) into objects sharing the same name key. My current array is:

```
brands: [
  0:ZARA: {product: "ZARA Black Shiny Shirt"}
  1:ZARA: {fit: "Slim Fit"}
  2:ZARA: {size: "46"}
  3:H&M: {product: "H&M Black Shirt"}
  4:H&M: {fit: "Regular Fit"}
  5:H&M: {size: "44"}
]
```

I want to construct a new array based on sets of arrays:

```
brands: [
  0:ZARA: {product: "ZARA Black Shiny Shirt",fit: "Slim Fit",size: "46"},
  1:H&M: {product: "H&M Black Shirt",fit:50 "Regular Fit",size: "44"}
]
```

Comment: please add valid data and what you have tried.

Comment: Removed PHP tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming an array of nested object, then you could iterate the array, find the object with the wanted key and apply the most inner object to the given obejct.

```js
var brands = [{ ZARA: { product: "ZARA Black Shiny Shirt" } }, { ZARA: { fit: "Slim Fit" } }, { ZARA: { size: "46" } }, { 'H&M': { product: "H&M Black Shirt" } }, { 'H&M': { fit: "Regular Fit" } }, { 'H&M': { size: "44" } }],
    result = brands.reduce((r, o) => {
        Object.entries(o).forEach(([k, v]) => {
            var temp = r.find(q => k in q);
            if (!temp) r.push(temp = { [k]: {} });
            Object.assign(temp[k], v);
        });
        return r;
    }, []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just need to loop over it and combine.

```js
var brands = [
  {ZARA: {product: "ZARA Black Shiny Shirt"}},
  {ZARA: {fit: "Slim Fit"}},
  {ZARA: {size: "46"}},
  {'H&M': {product: "H&M Black Shirt"}},
  {'H&M': {fit: "Regular Fit"}},
  {'H&M': {size: "44"}}
]

/* First step loop over the items and look to combine the same ones */
var combined = brands.reduce((obj, entry) => {
  // split it up into its part, the item and the detail of it
  const [key, detail] = Object.entries(entry)[0]
  // if we have not seen this item yet, set it
  if (!obj[key]) obj[key] = {}
  // Add the new item details to the item
  obj[key] = {...obj[key], ...detail}
  // return the updated object to the reduce method
  return obj
}, {})

// show the object we built with the combined details
console.log(combined)

// now you want it to be an array of objects so need to loop to make that
var finalOutput = Object.entries(combined)
  .reduce((out, [key, obj]) => {
    out.push({[key]: obj})    
    return out
}, [])

console.log(finalOutput)
```